# Transform generator that returns class with two values into dictionary pythonicly?

Tags: python, dictionary, generator

I have a generator that takes a dictionary and generates a class containing the key & value and returns that. I would like to recreate the dictionary from that.

```
class Limits:
    self._info = {"Test":"Toast"}
    @property
    def absolute(self):
        for (name, value) in self._info['absolute'].items():
            yield AbsoluteLimit(name, value)

class AbsoluteLimit(object):
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
```

My dirty solution would be:

```
limits_dict = {}
for elem in Limits.absolute:
    limits_dict[elem.name]=elem.value
```

Is there a more pythonic way to create the dictionary?

The method in question is from https://github.com/openstack/python-novaclient/blob/master/novaclient/v2/limits.py

Comment: ...dictionary-comprehension?

Comment: what about using `@classmethod` instead of `@property` and call `Limits.absolute()`. Seems more consistent ( my pov ).

Comment: the method absolute is given by the API (see link for more information; if you are interested)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```py
limits_dict = {elem.name: elem.value for elem in Limits.absolute}
```

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware that dictionary comprehensions exist in python. I only knew about list comprehensions. I will accept this answer as soon as the necessary delay time is over.

Comment: @Natan ..and set-comprehension... tuple needs a trick `tp = tuple( elem for elem in iterator )`